# Emptying a PostgreSQL text array column in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql

`data = {string1,string2}`

The array data is fetched from PostgreSQL database that has a column of type text[] ie text array.

I need to empty this array.
OUTPUT: 
`data = {}`

Can I use 
`tablename.update_attributes!(data: "")` 
OR
`tablename.data.map!{ |e| e.destroy }`

Context:

```
EMAILS.each do |email|
    res = tablename.where('lower(email) = lower(?)',
      "#{email}")
    res.each do |u| 
        u.data.map! { |e| e.destroy } // this is where i want to empty the array
        end
        puts ""
    end;
end;
```

I am very new in Rails. Can someone suggest something I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Please, replace your line of code with this

```
u.data.map! { |e| e.update(data: []) }
```

Comment: Adding a quick explanation with this code sample can help improve this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The way to erase an array column is to set an empty array to it: `data: []`

You can use [update_all](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all) to update all retrieved records at once:

```
EMAILS.each do |email|
  tablename.where('lower(email) = lower(?)', email).update_all(data: [])
end
```